# Webpack ts-loader : change tsconfig filename

Tags: typescript, webpack, tsconfig, ts-loader

I have 2 tsconfigs, one for my dev build and one for my prod build.
I choose the tsconfig with the `-p` flag :
`tsc -p dev.tsconfig.json`

Ts-loader is looking for a tsconfig.json file. How can I specify another filename with the ts-loader?

```
module.exports = {
    entry : __dirname + "/src/app/main.ts",
    output : {
        path : __dirname + "/dist",
        filename : "bundle.js"
    },
   resolve : {
     extensions : ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".js", ".ts"]
   },
   module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts?$/, loader: "ts" }
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update** (Webpack 4): As noted in the comments, the syntax has changed as referenced in the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55607159/542251).

---

Webpack enables us to add custom options for each loader. All `ts-loader` configuration properties are described [here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader).

`configFileName` is the property you are looking for. It should be like this.

```
module.exports = {
    entry : __dirname + "/src/app/main.ts",
    output : {
        path : __dirname + "/dist",
        filename : "bundle.js"
    },
    resolve : {
        extensions : ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".js", ".ts"]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts?$/, loader: "ts" }
        ]
    },
    ts: {
        configFileName : 'dev.tsconfig.json'
    }
};
```

Comment: Perfect! So I'll do it so : `module.exports = env => ({ ts : { configFileName : env.build === 'dev' ? 'dev.tsconfig.json' : 'acc.tsconfig.json'' } })`

Comment: outdated. Documentation no longer mentions a `ts.configFileName` option

Comment: This no longer works, see [this answer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55607159/542251)

Comment: Not sure if they changed it, but the name of the option is: `configFile`: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#options. The name suggested in the answer makes webpack throw an error.

Answer (score 48):

In Webpack 4 you need to specify the options into a `use` object:

```
use: [{
    loader: 'ts-loader',
    options: {
        configFile: "tsconfig.webpack.json"
    }
}]
```

Complete Webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + '/index.ts',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'your-library-name.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'ts-loader',
                    options: {
                        configFile: "tsconfig.webpack.json"
                    }
                }],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            }
        ]
    },
    mode: 'development',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
    },
    devtool: false
};
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Also note that for others still struggling, from the ts-loader docs if you are providing a relative path to a tsconfig "It will be resolved relative to the respective .ts entry file."

Answer (score 26):

Here is how to specify `configFile` (formerly `configFileName`, as Frank notes), as of December 2017 (Webpack 3.10.0).

### Webpack config

**Note:** [Since version 2](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/), Webpack has been using `module.rules` rather than `module.loaders`, and has deprecated use of query params in favour of an `options` object.

```
module.exports = {
    entry:  {
        "./build/bundle" : "./src/startup/Entry.ts"
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        libraryTarget: 'this'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        modules: [".", "node_modules"],
        extensions: [".js", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".d.ts", ".ts", ".tsx"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                loader: "ts-loader",
                options: {
                    configFile: "webpack_configs/tsconfig.webpack.json"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: []
};
```

### Directory structure

The root of my directory structure looks like:

```
webpack.config.js
webpack_configs/tsconfig.webpack.json
tsconfig.json
package.json
src/*
test/*
node_modules/*
build/*
```

... Where `*` indicates multiple files.

### Typescript config

`tsconfig.webpack.json` itself just extends my generic `tsconfig.json` by excluding the `test` folder:

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig",
     "exclude": [
       "node_modules",
       "test"
     ]
}
```

... But you needn't have two webpack configs to benefit from the `configFile` setting; you could simply use it to target your singular `tsconfig.json` from a custom location.

Comment: This does not work anymore for WebPack 4. See solution in my answer on this page.

Answer (score 11):

More like below:

```
{
   test: /\.tsx?$/, 
   loader: 'ts-loader',
   options: {configFile: 'tsconfig.webpack.json'} 
}
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-loader#configfile-string-defaulttsconfigjson

Answer (score 8):

Update @ September 6, 2017

`configFileName` has been deprecated in favor of `configFile` - [Source](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#configfilename-string-defaulttsconfigjson)

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment so I apologize for add this as an answer. Clearly someone didn't like that. =)

Answer (score 3):

Try using **configFile** after the loader name as querystring. Here is [webpack config](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html) and [**ts-loader**'s config](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader)

```
module.exports = {
   entry : "./main.ts",
   output : {
        path : __dirname + "/dist",
        filename : "bundle.js"
   },
   resolve : {
       extensions : ["", ".js", ".ts"]
   },
   module: {
     loaders: [
        { test: /\.ts?$/, loader: "ts-loader?configFile=src/tsconfig.server.json" }
     ]
   },
};
```